# Can't figure out how to make background scenes run in Pygame when "levels" change

Tags: python, loops, pygame, game-engine

I am new to python and wanted to create a game to test some knowledge. Please bare with my mistakes. I would also really appreciate an example written out if possible so I can wrap my head around the concept.

I couldn't figure out how to post the entire code without formatting nightmares so I put it in [github](https://github.com/fluxation87/pup/blob/master/game%20code) sorry if this is against terms!

I removed most of the dialogue because it was very very long.

Some background about the same:
It was written as a text-based only game first, then I heard about pygame wanted to figure out how to put the game into the window. So first I created all of the code, which ran perfectly fine even with sound effects / music, but then after trying to figure out pygame's game loop, I can't figure out how to change the background image.

I have 5 scenes that I want 5 images for, that change when I change the scene with user input. Even now, the music changes, but the background images don't change after blitting the first one in the 'naming' scene. I don't really understand how the pygame loop works in conjunction with the game engine I have currently. I know it's looping through the pygame loop as I tested it with printing things, but when trying to add images or saying if scene == naming: blit image, it doesn't work. I also tried putting the images into each of the scenes. I also tried putting the images into a class called background with all 5 scenes and images to each. Can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-M

Comment: I think for your starting off too complicated, you have many classes, probably dont need all of them. the biggest problem which could be causeing your problem is you have too many `pygame.display.flip()`s. You should have 1 and it should be in the main loop (unless you have multiple main loops). Because otherwise you start to get into problems such as fickering

Comment: if you don't know how to use debuger then use `print()` to see want you have in variables and which part of code is executed - maybe `scene == nameing` is never true beacuse you hava wrong values in variables. Other problem usually makes using `fill()` and `flip()` in wrong places and it draws background, next it clears it and finally `flip()` sends surface without expected background.

Comment: to make code more readable put all classes and functions directly after import - it  means before `pg.init()`. You use `current_scene` in `current_scene == Scene1():` but I can't find where you assigned value to `current_scene`. Besides, I can't find class `Scene()` also in code. And `if current_scene == Scene1()` is not good idea - you create `Scene1()` again and again in every loop and it may use different place in memory and it will treats it as different object. You should rather create some text values - ie `if current_scene == "scene1":`

Comment: BTW: if you put code on GitHub then use name with extension `.py` and it will highlight code - and it will be more readable.

Comment: You have to past the code in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use scenes. This is not the only way of doing it, but i though it would be easy to use/understand. I also noticed in your code that you used `input()`. which is annoying if your using a window, so i also added a button and a textbox input that kinda works.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init() # initialize the pg
win = pg.display.set_mode((1080, 720)) # create the game window
pg.display.set_caption("Puppy Love")
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

clock = pg.time.Clock()
fps = 60


class Scene:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sceneNum = 1

    def Scene_1(self):
        win.fill(white)
        if next_scene_button.draw(): #if clicked button
            self.sceneNum += 1
        name_Box.Draw()
        #anything else you want to draw

    def Scene_2(self):
        win.fill((0,0,255))
        if next_scene_button.draw():
            self.sceneNum = 1
        #...

    def Draw_Scene(self):
        if self.sceneNum == 1:
            self.Scene_1()
        elif self.sceneNum == 2:
            self.Scene_2()


class Button:
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h,text):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.text = text
        self.font = pg.font.Font(pg.font.match_font("Calibri"),20)

    def draw(self):
        button_clicked = False
        col = (150,150,150)
        if mouse_pos[0] > self.x and mouse_pos[0] < self.x + self.w:
            if mouse_pos[1] > self.y and mouse_pos[1] < self.y + self.h:
                col = (200,200,200)
                if click:
                    button_clicked = True
        pg.draw.rect(win,col,(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))
        obj = self.font.render(self.text,True, black)
        win.blit(obj,(self.x + (self.w-obj.get_width())//2,self.y + (self.h-obj.get_height())//2)) #center the text
        return button_clicked #return if the button was clicked or not

class TextBox:

    def __init__(self,x = 0, y = 0, w = 0, h = 0, text = "", background = False, font_size = 30, font = "Calibri", text_colour = (0,0,0)):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.text_colour = text_colour
        self.text = text
        self.background = background
        self.font = pg.font.Font(pg.font.match_font(font),font_size)

    def Add_char(self,key):
        if key == 8:
            self.text = self.text[:-1]
        else:
            char = pg.key.name(key)
            self.text += char

    def Draw(self):
        if self.background:
            pg.draw.rect(win, self.background, (self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h))
        obj = self.font.render(self.text,True,self.text_colour)
        win.blit(obj,(self.x,self.y))

    def Get_pos(self):
        return (self.x,self.y)


name_Box = TextBox(x=100, y=200, w=150, h=40, background=(200,200,200))

Scenes = Scene()
next_scene_button = Button(400,400,100,50,"next scene")

click = False
mouse_pos = [0,0]

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(fps)
    Scenes.Draw_Scene()


    mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    click = False

    pg.display.update() #no diference between .flip() and .update()
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            running = False    
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = True
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if Scenes.sceneNum == 1:
                name_Box.Add_char(event.key)
```

The main thing to take away from this is to only use one `pygame.display.flip()`. Hopefully you can use this to improve your program

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. While I love the functionality of the "next scene" button, as the game is text based and you move between scenes depending on your choice of text, I can't put that button in. I was hoping for some guidance related to your answer about how to use the input box that you created to change the scenes? 

For ex:

"You have 3 paths to take, press 1 for left, 2 for middle, 3 for right."
Left path(1)- sends player back to answer the same question again. 
Middle(2)- previous scene 
Right(3)-next scene. Does that make sense?

Comment: As a second follow up from the original question~ since the text will scroll down while the user reads it on the game window, where would all of the text be placed inside the code? Would I create an extremely long class (1 class) for all of the text, even if the text is on different "levels", or would I put the text inside the Scene_x functions inside the Scene class? I know that is just part of the problem as I'd need a way to actually write the words to the screen, but the first step for me is to find where to write it out lol. Thanks so much.

Comment: @MichaelW Yep, totaly understand, the program was to show that you can use buttons instead of `input`. Ive also made a text adventure game and know what you mean. The button doesnt have to change scenes, it can do what you want. For the "press 1 to do..." You dont need to use the inputbox to do that, you could just wait for the user to press one of the options, the input box is if they need to type a word. As for storing the text, i dont know what the best thing to do is, i have been in similar situations and never found a 'best option'.

Comment: You could do what you are doing now, or store it all in a text file and open it up in the program, you could also have a sql database, there are many option. do what ever seems easiest. I personally dont like the text in the code and use a text file

Comment: Thanks very much. Really appreciate the help and I will probably go ahead and use more buttons as input as you suggested instead of user input!!